# Unexpectedly found nil while assigning TO an optional

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel

In the code below, in func setTimer(timer:Timer) I am assigning timer.timeLabel to timerLabel.text. When I run that code, it gives me an error, saying that "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value." I'm certain that it isn't referring to timer.timerlabel because I can run print(timer.timerlabel) and it prints the string. Therefore, that value isn't nil.

When I attempt to manually set timerLabel.text = "", I get the same error on that line. This means that the warning concerns the variable I'm assigning to, not the one I'm assigning from.

The same thing happens with the other labels as well (hoursLabel.text = time.hours, etc.)

QUESTION: Why should it matter if the value I'm assigning to is nil? What might be causing this, considering that I'm using similar code in a tableViewCell and it works fine? I've attempted rebuilding the viewController and reconnecting all the IBOutlets. I've cleaned the project and still no luck.

```
import UIKit

class TimerControlVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var hoursLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var minutesLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var secondsLabel: UILabel!

let tf = TimeFormatter()

func setTimer(timer: Timer){

    print(timer.timerLabel)

    timerLabel.text = timer.timerLabel
    let time = tf.formatOutput(seconds: timer.time)
    hoursLabel.text = time.hours
    minutesLabel.text = time.minutes
    secondsLabel.text = time.seconds

  }

}
```

Comment: `timerLabel` is probably `nil`, and attempting to access it (implicitly force unwrapping, because it's an implicitly unwrapped optional) to get its `text` is causing the crash.

Comment: How are you creating the instance of `TimerControlVC`?  When are you calling `setTimer()`?

Comment: @vacawama In my original view controller: let TCVC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "timer_control") as! TimerControlVC)

Comment: The outlets are still `nil` until the view is loaded which happens when you push or present `TCVC`.

Comment: Override `viewDidLoad()` in `TimerControlVC` and add `print("view loaded")`.  Are you calling `setTimer()` before the view is loaded?  If so, the `@IBOutlet`s will still be `nil`.

Comment: Probably not related but avoid to name methods with leading `set...` because it could interfere with ObjC setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue might be in where you call the setTimer function.
Try to run it in viewDidLoad of TimeControlVC and see what happens.

You shouldn't call it (setTimer function) before pushing or presenting your view controller because the view is not set up yet hence it will crash by throwing nil error because they can't find the view that you want to assign to.

Comment: You and @vacawama were on the right track. I changed my code to present the view controller to self.present(TCVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Then I called the setTimer function from the previous view controller. Thank you! I thought that as long as you created an instance, it should work.

Comment: Nice one, no problem. Glad could help ! @AJL001

Answer (score 1):

`timerLabel` is probably `nil`, and attempting to access it (implicitly force unwrapping, because it's an implicitly unwrapped optional) to get its `text` is causing the crash.

Most likely, you have an `@IBOutlet` that isn't hooked up properly.

Comment: That's what I was extra careful to avoid when I rebuilt the view controller. I just double-checked: all the outlets are connected. That would give a different error anyway.

Comment: @AJL001 What is the value of `timerLabel` when you print it or inspect it in the dubber?

Comment: It wasn't the @IBOutlets at all, though I understand why you would think so. It was that I wasn't presenting the view controller before I was calling the setTimer function. Apparently it isn't enough to instantiate the VC. You must also present it before calling its methods.

Answer (score 0):

Can be some reasons

1. timerLabel is not connected to any label in storyboard. Check it.
2. Sometimes Xcode don't see changes in storyboard. Clean project and build it again.
3. You call this method before all views was created. For example if you call it from `init()` function. You should config UI in `viewDidLoad()`.
4. Check your `viewDidLoad()` and other overrided functions. Maybe you forgot to add super call.

Add more code. How you create this controller. How you call this func.